# Writing a Bash script to calculate averages

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell, zsh

I'm relatively new to Bash scripting, and finally thought of something that would be a good introduction to it. I have a collection of sorting programs I'm trying to time. Like most tests, it's good to get a large sample size, but it's hard to do it consistently. I figured that automating the process with a Bash script would be a good way to do it, but I don't do much Bash.

The sorting programs are written in C++ and output how long it took for them to sort an array of 10000 integer values read in from a file. I'm using a few different methods to sort the array, including bubble sort, quick sort, and parallelized (Boost threads) quick sort. At the end of their execution a time is output to the console and execution is halted. What I'd like to do in the Bash script is...

```
for 1 to 100:
    ./quicksortpar --this is the command to start the program
    take time reading from output, place in collection

--when that's done
for 1 to 100 in the collection:
    add each item in the collection to a running total

--when that's done
echo running total/ 100
```

How would I go about accomplishing this in Bash? Is it possible?

EDIT:

Here's the current Zsh script I have from Tony D's guidance:

[image]

Comment: Note that Bash does not do floating point arithmetic.  You will need use some other tool: `awk`, `bc`, `perl` or `python`, or … to do the arithmetic.  I recommend simply logging the raw output from your sort program to a file (so you have a permanent record — at least until you delete the file), which you can then analyze and reanalyze to your heart's content.  And use for comparisons between what you used a week ago and what you're using today, etc.  Make sure the output includes which sorting algorithm, how the data set was generated/shaped, and how big the data set was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Update: accidentally worked this out in zsh - doesn't work in bash)

```
TOTAL=0
for ((i=1; i<=100; i++))
do
    let TOTAL+=$(./quicksortpar)
done
let AVG=TOTAL/10
echo $AVG
```

Comment: when I run this, I get `./qsp_average.sh: line 9:`, a bunch of the time readings, and then `syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator`. Something in `let AVG=TOTAL/10`. For what it's worth, the values being spat out are usually decimals with six orders of magnitude behind the decimal.

Comment: @AaronMcRuer sorry - my mistake - I worked that out in (my normal) zsh by accident.  Let me see....

Comment: it would appear that you can't do floating point math in Bash (which I just found out), so I'll try your zsh solution.

Comment: @AaronMcRuer oh ok - I started to look at bash but then my other half dropped in for a chat.  Guess zsh's good if it's all the same to you (it handles floating point).

Comment: Tried in zsh, received `2:./qsp_average.sh: Syntax error: bad for loop variable`

Comment: @AaronMcRuer that's weird - I've got a complete script working now... from what I've posted earlier, I just needed to add the "let" prefixed to the "TOTAL+=" line.  The for syntax is working fine for me, but it could be a ZSH version thing - I'm using 5.0.2.  For older versions, you could try an alternative syntax - perhaps `for i in {1..100}` - seems the simplest from the huge number listed [here](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/1998/msg00735.html)

Comment: I went and changed the for loop to be `for i in {1 .. 10}`. That fixed the bad for loop variable problem, but I've come up with a few more. When I run it now, I get `4: ./qsp_average.sh: TOTAL+=0.001488: not found` in the shell, where `0.001488` is one of the times.

Comment: It's good to know the version; mine's 5.0.0. I'm also getting the "Let" not found error on the 4th and 6th lines.

Comment: @AaronMcRuer is that "not found" error even after putting "let" on the front of that line?  Note that the "let" command *must* be lower case.

Comment: added a picture of the current code based on your recommendations in the main post.

Comment: @AaronMcRuer are you sure you're executing the script in zsh?  You could put a `#!/bin/zsh` at the top, or make sure you `source` it from an interactive zsh session ala "source myscript" or ". myscript" (but not ./myscript).

Answer (score 2):

You can use gnu [bc](/questions/tagged/bc) for floating point arithmetic in bash. So do something like below

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a coll
for _ in  {1..100}; do
  coll+=("$(./quicksortpar)")
done

sum=0
for i in ${coll[@]}; do
  sum="$(echo "$sum + $i" | bc -l)"
done

echo "$sum / ${#coll[@]}" | bc -l
```

Note, the timings can be summed once instead of in a loop, per [Jonathan Leffler's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740206/writing-a-bash-script-to-calculate-averages/22740966#comment34661358_227409660)

```
sum=$( { printf "%d+" "${coll[@]}"; echo 0; } | bc -l)
```

Comment: Not sure if there is really a need for the second for loop, but kept it in to match your description.

Comment: this seems to accrue syntax errors on line 8. An example would be `./qsp_average.sh: line 8: ((: sum+=0.001485: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".001485")`.

Comment: @AaronMcRuer Woops, didn't realize the timing would have floating point as well. See update.

Comment: You can improve the performance of the summing with `sum=$(printf "%d+" "${coll[@]}"; echo 0; } | bc -l)`; this invokes `bc` just once instead of 100 times.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. Very useful suggestion in a lot of cases, added note in answer.

Comment: I'll give all of these scripts a try soon. It's a nice automated way to do the task, but one thing that does suffer is performance. Typically I'm seeing drops of around one order of magnitude in execution speed. I'm guessing that's due to the fact that zsh/bash is being run in its own process and is putting another layer of abstraction between each individual run of the program I'm testing.